# Image warp with VTK?

Tags: c++, image-processing, vtk

I'd like to warp a vtkImageData with a vector field, similar to what itk's WarpImageFilter does. the vtkGridTransform object seems promising, but there doesn't seem to be a vtkTransformImageFilter...

Is what I want to do at all possible with VTK?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, here's the answer:

> The filter for applying a transform to an image is vtkImageReslice,
>   and the relevant example is Hybrid/Testing/Tcl/TestGridWarp3D.tcl.
>
> The basics of deformable transformations in VTK are described
>   in the following paper:
>   "Generalized 3D nonlinear transformations for medical imaging:
>   an object-oriented implementation in VTK"
>   David G. Gobbi, Terry M. Peters
>   Computerized Medical Imaging and Graphics
>   July 2003 (Vol. 27, Issue 4, Pages 255-265)

Source: http://vtk.1045678.n5.nabble.com/Image-Warp-with-VTK-td1247962.html

Comment: This link is dead.